# Error in server build process

Tags: codenameone

Good day all
I just completed my codename one app and all went well while testing in the simulator, but on sending an android build it fails. I have checked the error log and cant seem to understand what the problem is. Below is the link showing the complete error log reported by the codename one server.
Link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/6f7fcr8l7fr1w4d/new%20error.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

This is the actual error from the log:

```
/tmp/build3509442697339141445xxx/myEvents/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myEvents/myEventsStub.java:65: error: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
            com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView adView = new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView(this);
                                      ^
/tmp/build3509442697339141445xxx/myEvents/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myEvents/myEventsStub.java:65: error: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
            com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView adView = new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView(this);
                                                                                     ^
/tmp/build3509442697339141445xxx/myEvents/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myEvents/myEventsStub.java:68: error: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
            adView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
                                                       ^
/tmp/build3509442697339141445xxx/myEvents/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myEvents/myEventsStub.java:69: error: package com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize does not exist
            AndroidImplementation.setViewAboveBelow(null, adView, 0, com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.SMART_BANNER.getHeightInPixels(this));
                                                                                                      ^
/tmp/build3509442697339141445xxx/myEvents/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myEvents/myEventsStub.java:70: error: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
            com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest adRequest = new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("C6783E2486F0931D9D09FABC65094FDF").build();
                                      ^
/tmp/build3509442697339141445xxx/myEvents/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myEvents/myEventsStub.java:70: error: package com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest does not exist
            com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest adRequest = new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("C6783E2486F0931D9D09FABC65094FDF").build();
                                                                                                     ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
6 errors
```

I'm guessing you defined the build hint `android.googleAdUnitId` or `google.adUnitId` which failed for some reason. AFAIK banner ads aren't used as often by our developers so it's possible something broke and no one noticed.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, I am still amazed at how quick you answer questions here. Thumbs up. I removed the banner ads build hint and  a new error log is been reported. Below is the link sir:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jxy2029i74dv4zz/Error%20doc.docx?dl=0

Comment: This seems to be the error: `Warning: com.parse4cn1.ParsePush: can't find referenced method ` it looks like parse was integrated incorrectly. Did you add parse manually? Did you follow the integration guide?